# generic method declaration within generic class. Boundaries allowing different for super and without it

Tags: java, generics, methods

What wrong in this method declaration?

```
public abstract class A<K extends Number>{  
   public abstract <K> A<K> useMe (A<K> k);
}
```

I see compile error:

```
java: type argument K is not within bounds of type-variable K
```

my first thought for this compile error was that as - It is not guaranteed that K is Number in my method declaration, that's why issue is coming.

But in another case as below:

```
public abstract <K> A<? extends Number> useMe (A<? super K> k);
```

`A<? super K>`  is again not guaranteed that it is Number (However IDE sign warning) but it is not compile error.

What are the differences?

Comment: This is rather surprising for me too. I would expect that signature to fail. Just for information, if I change `A<? super K>` to `A<? super Object>`, where `Object` is the erasure of `K` there, then it fails to compile. Looking for some answer that explains it well.

Comment: But my IDE say that it is compile error, but after manual comple I don't see compile errors

Comment: @RohitJain which compiler are you using? `A<? super Object>` as an argument type is compiling fine for me with both the javac and Eclipse compilers with source levels 1.7 and 1.8.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Doesn't work for me under JDK 1.8.0 - build 129. And neither in eclipse with source levels at 1.8

Comment: Ah I tried to many options and didn't see that you used super instead of extends. Try `super Double` or `extends Object` like in the answer below (not `super Object`). When ? is involved, things don't work the same. But try to make an invocation of the method useMe  in which you would invoke it with A<Object> - there's no way in which you can write that directly or indirectly.

Comment: Well, I was talking about using `A<? super Object>` instead of `A<? super K>` as in question. Later one compiles, but former doesn't. :(

Comment: java version "1.7.0_45" I see behaviour according  Rohit Jain explanation

Comment: `A<? super K>` where `class A<T extends Number` is not equivalent to `A<? super Object>` but to `A<? super Number>`. You can verify this using a test method `public void test(A<?> a) { A<Number> b = null; a.useMe(b); }`, which is valid, but if you declare b as `A<Double>` it  doesn't compile.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The `K` used there is a different type parameter, that has no bounds. So, it's erasure would be `Object`.

Comment: @RohitJain I don't think erase applies here, at least not as you say it. Erasure gets rid of all the generics, so the erasure is `A`, not `A<? super Object>`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yeah I know that. I was just thinking that, since the bounds to `K` is just `Object`, I assumed `A<? super Object>` should also work, instead of `A<? super K>`. But I think I was wrong. I'm getting close to the answer, and will post it soon.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt gstackoverflow. Added an answer. Hope that will clear it.

Comment: @Rohit Jain I try to digest it

Comment: @gstackoverflow Seems like my derivation of concept was a bit wrong. Here's the [same question posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752781/lower-bounded-wildcard-not-checked-against-upper-bounded-type-parameter?rq=1), where it's mentioned that perhaps Java doesn't do bound check with lower bounded wildcard. You might want to have a look.

Comment: Thanks, I will make it.

Comment: @Rohit Jain I frustrated when users see problem with generic advise to research erasure mindless. I see that generic in java created so  bad that people with huge experience (as Rohit Jain ) cannot understand generic construction exact. it is upseted for me.

Answer (score 1):

remove extends Number from class and add it with method i.e.
`public abstract class A<T>{
    public abstract <T  extends Number> A<T> useMe(A<T> t);
}`

Comment: Removing `extends Number` from `<T extends Number>` on the class changes the meaning of the declaration the class. Yes, it may make it compile but now it means something different.

Comment: @Karsan what should I see ?

Comment: use this 
public abstract class A<K extends Number>{  
   public abstract A<K> useMe(A<K> k);
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a different answer.
The reason is that though you use `<K>` as a generic in your method, it has nothing to do with the `<K>` you used in your class. It would be more obvious if you wrote

```
abstract class A<K extends Number>{
    public abstract <T> A<T> useMe(A<T> t);
}
```

Here `<T>` is some generic, but you have limited A to only use generics which extend `Number` and `<T>` in this case doesn't and it fails to implement the contract of A. Here is where the error comes from. For that reason you should write

```
abstract class A<K extends Number>{
    public abstract <T extends Number> A<T> useMe(A<T> k);
}
```

Comment: No, I want to understand cause of problem.  I just investigate generics

Comment: @gstackoverflow, gave a different answer

Comment: I don't understand why **public abstract <K> A<? extends Number> useMe (A<? super K> k);** is valid at this case ?

Comment: @svz is correct. Your declaration of type variable<K> in the method is shadowing the declaration in the class, which is hidden because of this. So you're now saying that your method can return any A<T> without restricting T to a subclass of Number - but that is incompatible with the way in which class A is declared, which does require it to be a subclass of Number.

Comment: You are completely missing the question. OP understand why the first case fails to compile. What he's asking is, why the second case compiles fine? Which is rather surprising for me too.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Where do you see in the answer an explanation for the second case - `public abstract <K> A<? extends Number> useMe (A<? super K> k);`?

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, you're right. The local shadowing of <K> is a bit of a red herring in the question, it has nothing to do with the problem. `useMe(A<? extends Object> k)`, `useMe(A<? super Double> k)` and `useMe(A<?> k)` are all valid ways to declare the method and the compiler restricts these automatically to subclasses of `Number`. Can't quickly find where this is in the JLS though.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I don't understand how `? super Object` would work. I wouldn't expect it to, and neither it compiles. If this works, that would mean, we can give higher bounds to the type argument, than what is specified in type parameter. So, why would just giving `A<T>` won't work.